# JSON and java servlet

Tags: java, mysql, json, servlets

I have a html login page, where the user has to put in a number and if this number is registered in the database the user is redirected to a certain site. If the number is not in the database the user get's to see an error message. At the moment I am doing this with a java servlet a local mySql database and tomcat 8.0 and it works perfectly. But I need to use a remote database by accessing it with JSON, I filled the database with a poster addon on mozilla firefox and I can see what is in the database. So it needs to check the user input on the HTML page with the data in the database via json and grant access or not. This is my java servlet that connects to my mysql database.

```
 import java.io.*;
    import javax.servlet.*;
    import javax.servlet.http.*;
    import java.sql.*;

    public class servlet extends HttpServlet{

      public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,
                        HttpServletResponse response)
                throws ServletException, IOException
      {
          String Ticketnumber = request.getParameter("Ticketnumber");

          if(Ticketnumber.length() >= 16 || Ticketnumber.length() <= 14){
                response.sendRedirect("http://localhost:8080/Error.html");
          }

          String DB_URL="jdbc:mysql://localhost/ticketnumbers";
          String USER = "root";
          String PASS = "password";

          try{
             Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

             Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL, USER, PASS);

             final String sql;
             sql = "select Ticketnumber from users where Ticketnumber='"+ Ticketnumber +"' limit 1";
             PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
             ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery();

             if(rs != null && rs.next()){  
                response.sendRedirect("http://localhost:8080/Welcome.html");
             }else{
                response.sendRedirect("http://localhost:8080/Error.html");
             }

             stmt.close();
             conn.close();
          }catch(SQLException se){
             se.printStackTrace();
          }catch(Exception e){
             e.printStackTrace();
          }finally{   
          }
       }
      public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,
                        HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
        doGet(request, response);
      }
    }
```

Comment: Your question isn't clear.

Answer (score 0):

I think with "a remote database by accessing it with JSON" you mean a remote **Web Service**.

You will first need to download the JSON data by [making a Java HTTP request](http://www.drdobbs.com/jvm/making-http-requests-from-java/240160966) and then parsing the retrieved string as JSON using a parser library ([GSON is very good for this](https://github.com/google/gson)).

After that, you can do your logic and validate the Ticketnumber against the parsed JSON object.

You will not need to connect to any database since you will get the data via HTTP, the same way you get them via Poster in Firefox. Poster does not know what database (if any) is being used by the remote site, it only needs the URL.